# Recover a RAID5 logical volume with two failed devices

Tags: linux, software-raid, lvm

before bashing me I assure you I know a RAID5 devices can survive only one drive failure. So... why am I asking this?

I had two disks disconnected simultaneously from my machine, so raid failed. Also vg wasn't able to start again due to the missing drives.

Fixing the VG was simple: I told the machine to add the disks again. They were fine, so it didn't complained.

Since both drives went offline at the same time I'm pretty sure the data is all there too, but of course raid5 is not designed to start with two missing disks.

I'm ready to let this go, but I have a couple of terabyte to restore and I would also miss a chance to learn, so before giving up I'm trying to fix my logical volume.

Down to the technicalities: I've used *vgextend --restoremissing datavg /dev/mapper/<hdd_names>* to mark the missing pvs available again, but I get **md/raid:mdX: not enough operational devices(2/4 failed)** when I try to activate the lv. Another thing: I used lvm raid, not mdadm's (which seems more forgiving)

Is there any chance I can simply tell the raid there are no failed disks and just use them?

Thanks in advance, even if the answer is no :)